# convert string to valid url content

Tags: python, url, parameters

I need to share a link like this

```
mysite.com?url=https://anothersite.com&text=some text
```

so it must be like this

```
mysite.com?url=https%3A%2F%anothersite.com&text=some%20text
```

I could get it using this approach

```
def URL():
    try:
        text = 'some text'
        url = 'anothersite.com'
        parameters = 'url=%s&text=%s' % (url , text)
        for r,n in [(':','%3A') , (' ','%20') , ('/','%2F')]:
            parameters = parameters.replace(r,n)
        return 'mysite.com?%s' % parameters
    except Exception as e:
       print '%s (%s)' % (e.message, type(e))
       return ""
```

It works, but I have to specify every character, so if my text has a '#' I must add , ('#','%23') to my list.

Is there a good way to solved this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [urllib.quote](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote) and `str.index` to split string (if you need to split):

```
link = 'mysite.com?url=https://anothersite.com&text=some text'

>>> link[:link.index('=')] + '=' + urllib.quote(link[link.index('=')+1:])
'mysite.com?url=https%3A//anothersite.com%26text%3Dsome%20text'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be interested in the `safe` kwarg to `urllib.parse.quote`:

```
qs = 'mysite.com?url=https://anothersite.com&text=some text'

urllib.parse.quote(qs,safe='=?&')
Out[10]: 'mysite.com?url=https%3A%2F%2Fanothersite.com&text=some%20text'
```

from the docs:

> RFC 2396 Uniform Resource Identifiers (URI): Generic Syntax lists the
>   following reserved characters.
>
> reserved    = ";" | "/" | "?" | ":" | "@" | "&" | "=" | "+" |
>                 "$" | ","

Of the above reserved characters you appear to want to keep `=?&` unescaped in your query string, so tell it so.  It will escape the rest.